# ListDensityPlot of a data set in polar coordinates

Tags: plotting, interpolation, data

I have this data set composed of a table of `{r,f[r]}`. I want to make a density plot of the data. It should look like the picture. The data is not normalized like the picture (some help with that would be appreciated) Can you help me?

Data avaliabe at:
http://pastebin.com/nLn1c5ff

[image]

Comment: Have a look [ListDensityPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/nLn1c5ff", "Table"];
fR = Interpolation[data];
DensityPlot[fR[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

I'm not sure how precisely you want to match your image. But it can be done by playing with `ColorFunction`

Comment: I don't need to match the image, it is just a guide. But that solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[data], ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
{min, max} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]
```

> {1.10589*10^-8, 11.7826}

```
scaled = Transpose @ {data[[All, 1]], (data[[All, 2]] - min)/(max - min)};

GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[scaled], ListPlot[scaled, PlotRange -> All]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Differently:

```
toplot = Flatten[#, 1] & @
   Table[{scaled[[i, 1]] Cos[t], scaled[[i, 1]] Sin[t], 
     scaled[[i, 2]]}, {t, 0, 2 π, 0.1}, {i, 1, Length @ scaled, 5}];

ListDensityPlot[toplot, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, All}, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

Or another way of visualisation:

```
f = Interpolation[scaled];

r = RevolutionPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but in your approach there are less data points per $dx dy$ when $r$ is large. So I decided to go with interpolation of data in polar coordinates, so the `DensityPlot` will decide how accurately it has to sample it .

Comment: @BlacKow I took every fifth point from `data` because it took a long time to render the image. I think there is enough data to yield no perceivable difference. I wanted to use `Interpolation` like you did, but you were faster ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using your `data`

```
{rmin, rmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(*  {2.04082*10^-7, 10.}  *)

{fmin, fmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]

*  {1.10589*10^-8, 11.7826}  *)
```

Normalizing the function to be in the interval {0,1}

```
f = Interpolation[
   {#[[1]], (#[[2]] - fmin)/(fmax - fmin)} & /@
    data];

Plot[f[r], {r, rmin, rmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The first minimum (**EDIT**) occurs at

```
m = r /. FindRoot[f'[r] == 0, {r, 4}]

(*  3.83171  *)

DensityPlot[
 f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m},
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be "the first minimum occurs" instead of "the first zero occurs"? Since you are solving for derivative = 0?

Comment: @BlacKow - corrected. Thanks.